# In CakePHP, how do I set up a "one-to-(one of three)" relationship?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have three disticnt models, say A, B and C. These are different and couldn't really be merged into one. They share one common element which I have made a separate model, D. What is the best/easiest/standard way to set up this relationship in Cake?

Currently each model A, B, C has an id "D_id" which relate to model D. Though this creates some strange stuff like D being viewed as the "parent model" which isn't the case as it is one of the models A-C.

Comment: I would say hasOne would be the most appropriate relationship to access the D element. belongsTo is a similar association that makes D a "parent model", but hasOne seems to be the logical choice.

Comment: Exactly, I thought that hasOne would be the logical choice, the problem is that this places the key in the D model and thus cannot with this alone determine if it should select the record with id X from model A, B or C. Is there a way to create some combination of model+id so that model D know it sohuld select id X from model B for example?

Comment: It would help if you gave us a description or even a name for each model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each model, A, B, and C should "belongsTo" D.

D should "hasMany" A, B, and C.

This will make it so A, B, and C each have a "D_id" field which references a row in D.

For a GREAT explanation of CakePHP's associations, [check out this site](http://jbenner.net/blog/understanding-cakephp-associations).

Comment: Even though it doesn't make "logical" sense this is indeed the correct way to set this up.  It would help to know that data the models represent though.

Comment: Yeah - the naming of the associations don't always follow what you'd think they'd be.